# C++: why doesn't weak_ptr have a shared_ptr&& constructor?

Tags: c++, std

The C++ draft standard [mandates](http://eel.is/c++draft/util.smartptr.weak.const) the following constructors for `weak_ptr`:

```
weak_ptr(const weak_ptr& r) noexcept;
template<class Y> weak_ptr(const weak_ptr<Y>& r) noexcept;
template<class Y> weak_ptr(const shared_ptr<Y>& r) noexcept;

weak_ptr(weak_ptr&& r) noexcept;
template<class Y> weak_ptr(weak_ptr<Y>&& r) noexcept;
```

I'm surprised to not see the following constructor:

```
template<class Y> weak_ptr(shared_ptr<Y>&& r) noexcept;
```

Of course the existing constructor from const reference to `shared_ptr` works functionally in any context where the rvalue reference version would work. But I believe the latter would allow saving at least two atomic operations in the case where the caller wants to destructively convert a shared reference to a weak one by using a `shared_ptr` rvalue to initialize a `weak_ptr`.

Comment: should `weak_ptr` know anything about the existence of `shared_ptr`?

Comment: What will you save? Currently `weak_ptr` constructor only needs to increment weak counter, and, later, when `shared_ptr` is destroyed, decrement shared counter (and potentially destroy pointed object). WIth your proposed move constructor it would need to increment weak counter, decrement shared counter (and potentially destroy pointed object). Same operations, just executed earlier.

Comment: @BradAllred Yes. It should know about its existence (`weak_ptr` has constructors taking it already, and can be converted to it) and about shared control block structure.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot: indeed you're right (at least in my copy of libstdc++); I had misunderstood the structure of the shared count. If you submit that as an answer I'm happy to mark it accepted.

Answer (score 4):

A `weak_ptr<>` holds a non-owning pointer to an object managed by a `shared_ptr<>`. The object is deleted when the last `shared_ptr<>` reference to it is deleted.

If the constructor you miss would exist, it could happen that you pass the last existing `shared_ptr<>` as parameter, which would destroy the object in the process of the move. So you would be left with a `weak_ptr<>` that points to an already deleted object.

Does not make much sense, right?

Comment: I don't think this is the answer. Obviously the semantics would be that you wind up with an empty weak pointer, just as if you call the existing const reference constructor with a temporary `shared_ptr` (e.g. a return value from a function) that is immediately destroyed. After all, becoming empty after the last reference is dropped is the entire point of `weak_ptr`.

Comment: @jacobsa In that case, you are right of course (but nobody does that anyway, right?). But with your new constructor you would always end up with an empty weak pointer, unless there actually was (at least) a second shared_ptr reference before. I can't see a use case for such a behaviour.

Comment: @jacobsa I don't see any possible uses where doing this would be the most elegant solution.